# Is it appropriate to thank users for their answers on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, comments, thanks

I know stackoverflow wants to be very concise about their questions and answers, so I was thinking that they may not want formalities mixed in with the Q&A. To be clear, I am asking if "Thanks!" and "You've been very helpful!" belong in comments. Any thoughts?

Comment: Relevant, possibly a duplicate: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950). Or are you asking about comments?

Comment: Thank you for helping me specify! Yes, I mean in comments. For instance, I just had two people give me very helpful answers and was wondering if it would be suitable for me to thank them :)

Comment: It is suitable to thank them by upvoting their answers, and possibly marking one as accepted. Otherwise, see the following post:

Comment: Ah! Ironically, thank you for the link